# Javascript display DIV on DDL Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ddl

Know little Javascript was hoping someone can help me out. Depending on the value in the DDL I'm trying to get a DIV to show.

Here is what I have so far:

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="SearchTypeDDL" runat="server" onchange="searchType();" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Select Search type" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Coordinates" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Postcode / Town" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>               
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Javascript:

```
function searchType() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=SearchTypeDDL.ClientID %>");
        if (ddl.selectedIndex == '1') {
            $('#coordinates').show();
        } else {
            $('#coordinates').hide();
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Added an alert to check the value being passed:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("ddl");
        var SelectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex;
        alert(SelectedIndex);
        if (ddl.selectedIndex == '1') {
            $('#coordinates').show();               
        } else {
            $('#coordinates').hide();
        }
```

The alert is showing '1' but it's skipping the IF statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has a similar problem, here is what I used to get it working

```
function searchType() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("ddl");
        var SelectedIndex = ddl.selectedIndex;           
        if (SelectedIndex == '1') {
            document.getElementById('coordinates').style.display = "block";                             
        } else (SelectedIndex== '1') {
            document.getElementById('coordinates').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is not working?

I copied your code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0oqLh6py/) and it seems to work just fine

```
<select id="ddl" onChange="searchType()">
  <option value="-1">Select Search Type</option>
  <option value="1">Coordinates</option>
  <option value="2">Postcode</option>
</select>

<div id="coordinates" style="display:none">
  Coordinates div
</div>

window.searchType = function () {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("ddl");
  if (ddl.selectedIndex == '1') {
    $('#coordinates').show();
  } else {
    $('#coordinates').hide();
  }
}
```